# How does Spark rdd.collectAsMap() work? Why the time it costs increase during training process?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Using Spark for Model training, the broadcast params is updated during training, and at the front of each iteration, I collect the rdd `params` as Map using

```
broadcast_params = sc.broadcast(params.collectAsMap())
...
update(params)
```

But I found that the time cost at the `collectAsMap()` step is increasing... Why would this happens?

Answer (score 0):

collectAsMap will fetch the result into driver side. So if the result size is large, then it will take a long time. You didn't mention what algoritm you use for training, I guess you use some kind of iterative algorithm, and the result size will increase after several rounds of interation.

Comment: I used EM algorithm. So the params only update value but not the size.. The size of params keeps same...So kind confused about it...